# Input text box not recognising in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I am working in a page created with the help of sharepoint .

In that page , we have one  tag.

```
<input name="SearchBox" title="Search..." class="" id="" accessKey="S" onkeydown="" onkeypress="" onfocus="" onblur="" type="text" maxLength="2048" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" value="test"/>
```

something like the above

In IE9 and above , chrome I am fetching the value of the text box and I am passing that value to another function . It is working fine

But In IE8 , if i tried to fetch like document.getElementsByName('SearchBox')[0].value, it throwing error as **"SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined "**

---

I inspected the elements in developer tool of IE8. I am really surprised the input tag element is not able to inspect in IE8 . Then I opened the html in developer tool and I saw the  element is missing in html file . But it is rendering in page. How come is it possible. Can anyone help me regarding this ?

We used sharepoint 2013.

Comment: You'll have to update your question to include a *minimal* example that causes the problem you are describing.  As it is now, we can only guess.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

You should allow the blocked content:

HTML:

```
<input name="SearchBox" title="Search..." class="" id="txt1" accessKey="S" onkeydown="" onkeypress="" onfocus="" onblur="" type="text" maxLength="2048" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" value="test"/>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var val=$("#txt1").val();
alert(val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with JQuery?

`$("input[name='SearchBox']).val();`

Comment: Ya i used .. as i updated the question , input element is not present in HTML that is in developer tool. But rendering in browser